# Trying to fix double-encoding in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess, is it possible to convert urls to lowercase, but allow uppercase encoding?

Current file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].* [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].* 
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}}?${lc:%{QUERY_STRING}} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^client/(.*) client.php?q=type:$1 [QSA]
```

- Browser: domain.com/client/city?mf[]=liverpool (correct)
- Googlebot: domain.com/client/city?mf%5d%5b=liverpool (301, incorrect)

If I remove [NE], the resulting url is double encoded:

- Browser: domain.com/client/city?mf%255b%255d=liverpool (200, but
  incorrect results)
- Googlebot:    domain.com/client/city?mf%255b%255d=liverpool (200, but
  incorrect results)

Desired output:

- Browser: domain.com/client/city?mf[]=liverpool (correct)
- Googlebot: domain.com/client/city?mf%5D%5B=liverpool (200, correct)

I'm forcing lowercase using RewriteMap as the previous site was mixed case, with far too many combinations to manage. Have spent the whole day reviewing threads, but can't seem to isolate the problem.. or perhaps I'm looking at this the wrong way.

Thank you.

Comment: Strange: RewriteMap is usually not available in .htaccess scope, valid scopes are : `server config, virtual host`, so in real configuration files and not in dynamic .htaccess files.

Comment: I added RewriteMap to httpd.conf (was just trying to provide as much detail as possible) - "RewriteMap lc int:tolower". Lower-case works well, I just need to exclude the encoded characters.

Comment: Interesting problem. I know query strings aren't url decoded, while REQUEST URI is. Could be quite complex. Do you know where Googlebot is finding his source URL? maybe you have a bad sitemap.xml with double url encoding?

Comment: Wish it was a bad sitemap - I'm testing the source URL using fetch as google in WMT (which produces a circular 301). I would like to remove [] from the url, which would eliminate this problem, but it's beyond my scope. I'm almost there with .htaccess.. figure the problem has to do with 2 rewrites, but don't know how to combine lines 3 & 4 into one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution, which is good enough for my purposes.. based on regilero's comments, I decided to remove the RewriteCond for {QUERY_STRING}. This is the new code:

```
RewriteRule ^client/(.*) client.php?q=type:$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*
RewriteRule ^ ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

The above results in the following:

- Browser: domain.com/client/city?mf[]=Liverpool (correct)
- Googlebot: domain.com/client/city?mf%5D%5B=Liverpool (200, correct)

The reason I need ALL lowercase sitewide is due to the previous site structure - the above array is a feature that has never been indexed (due to canonical links), so I can live with a query that is mixed case.

I hope this helps someone else!